# Spring boot application reads messages from kafka after deleting them

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have spring boot application which reads messages from Kafka and I can't understand one behavior. I have set kafka properties regarding max poll size to:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      max-poll-records: 5
    listener:
      ack-mode: record
      concurrency: 1
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer: DEBUG
```

And I can see that messages are read in packages by 5 in each:

```
2023-08-04T13:21:25.053+02:00 DEBUG [,] 12001 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 5 records
//Handling first 4 messages
2023-08-04T13:21:57.114+02:00  INFO [,] 12001 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] SomeListener: Handling command message

2023-08-04T13:22:05.134+02:00 DEBUG [,] 12001 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 5 records
2023-08-04T13:22:05.135+02:00  INFO [,] 12001 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] SomeListener: Handling command message
//Handling next 4 messages
```

I sent 200 messages to topic and deleted them (with kafka-ui and also by setting `retention.ms`) after processing started to check if application really fetch 5 messages in poll. But even if messages are not in the topic application still is able to read all messages which are sent. I can't understand why. Is it a normal behaviour that kafka allows consumer which already started to read all messages, even these deleted?

Comment: I suggest you print the offsets of each 5, not just a count

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting messages after processing has started, so how are you sure that you deleted them before application could read them?

By default messages are retained for 7 days. In Kafka is not a message queue so there is no provision of deleting the messages. You can just move the read pointer ahead so previous messages are not read again.

Comment: Each message is processed ~8seconds and I can see in logs which message is comitted. I delete all messages immediately after they appear on topic. 

Yeah I know that there is no provision of deleting the messages. It was done just for test purposes to check if max-poll-records works. And then I observed this strange (at least for me) behavior and I want to understand why they are still accessible for application and they are not visible on topic anymore.

Comment: "no provision of deleting the messages" - Then explain the `kafka-delete-records.sh` script

Comment: Ah I misunerstood the original message - at first I meant that is no benefit of deleting the messages.